# more-ing or less-ing output in the python interpreter

Tags: python, debugging, interpreter

What is the best alternative to more-ing or less-ing multi-line output while running python in the interpreter mode?

Suppose, there exists an object variable `foo` which had many properties. A `dir(foo)` would dump onto the screen. We cannot inspect or page this output since you are presented with the interpreter prompt immediately.

Currently the only way to inspect such data is to store into a variable and view slices or it. For e.g.

```
>>> keys = dir(foo)
>>> len(keys)
120
>>> keys[10:20] #viewing the sub slice of keys
...
```

Hoping that there is an alternative to this. I know that `help()` does present with a more-like interface, but only for documentation of the object under consideration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`help`'s more-like interface is provided by the [`pydoc`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pydoc.html) module, in particular its undocumented method [`pager`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/pydoc.py#L1463). If you convert your data to a string (perhaps by using the [`pprint`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pprint.html) module for additional readability), you can send it to `pager` to get the interactive visualization you're looking for.

```
>>> import pydoc
>>> import pprint
>>> def more_vars(obj):
...     pydoc.pager(pprint.pformat(vars(obj)))
...
>>> import math
>>> more_vars(math)
{'__doc__': 'This module provides access to the mathematical functions\n'
            'defined by the C standard.',
 '__loader__': <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>,
 '__name__': 'math',
 '__package__': '',
 [not pictured: about 30 more lines of methods/attributes]
 'frexp': <built-in function frexp>,
 'fsum': <built-in function fsum>,
 'gamma': <built-in function gamma>,
-- More  --
```